# How to send video card in Teams botframework sdk3 C#

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#video-card), it seems video card can't be used in MSTeams. Is it possible now? Or any other ways to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the new Task Module feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview

The world did not need yet another video playback control and even if we did have one, it wouldn't support YouTube or Vimeo videos. Task module supports all of the use cases.